# Python webscraping from NCBI

Tags: python, web-scraping, taxonomy, ncbi

For a project i will need a list of all the virusnames in the family of a certain virus. Now there are many viruses in the family so i wanted to build a script for it. I have no experiance with Beautifulsoup or any other webscraping techniques but i gave it a go.

```
def souptime():
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?name=Orthomyxoviridae"
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(link.text)

souptime()
```

Now here i get some of the output i want but i also get Entrez PubMed and others and at the end all the disclaimer stuff. Now what i would like is for the script to get all the viruses in the family so in my testrun with orthomyxo viruses

[image]

it would skip the first three lines and start with the subtypes preferably. But i dont seem to be able to do this.

Is there anyone who knows how to do this properly? I would like to streamline this so it is possible for other virus families

Tried Beautiful soup, requesting the URL and manually with regex deleting the parts i dont need, but then its very hard to make it streamlined for other viruses. I am hoping someone knows how to do this and can tell me where i am going wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Select more specific to get all the virus:

```
soup.select('a[title="species"] + ul a')
```

##### Example

To get your information structured.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?name=Orthomyxoviridae"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

data = []

for s in soup.select('a[title="species"]:has(+ ul a)'):
    family = s.find_previous('a',attrs={'title':'family'}).text
    genus = s.find_previous('a',attrs={'title':'genus'}).text
    
    for v in s.find_next_sibling('ul').select('a'):
        data.append({
            'virus': v.text,
            'species': s.text,
            'genus': genus,
            'family': family
        })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### Output

|  | virus | species | genus | family |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | H10N1 subtype | Influenza A virus | Alphainfluenzavirus | Orthomyxoviridae |
| 1 | H10N2 subtype | Influenza A virus | Alphainfluenzavirus | Orthomyxoviridae |
| 2 | H10N3 subtype | Influenza A virus | Alphainfluenzavirus | Orthomyxoviridae |
| 3 | H10N4 subtype | Influenza A virus | Alphainfluenzavirus | Orthomyxoviridae |
| 4 | H10N5 subtype | Influenza A virus | Alphainfluenzavirus | Orthomyxoviridae |
| 19055 | Oz virus | Thogotovirus ozense | Thogotovirus | Orthomyxoviridae |
| 19056 | Sinu virus | Thogotovirus sinuense | Thogotovirus | Orthomyxoviridae |
| 19057 | Thailand tick thogotovirus | Thogotovirus thailandense | Thogotovirus | Orthomyxoviridae |
| 19058 | Thogoto virus (isolate SiAr 126) | Thogotovirus thogotoense | Thogotovirus | Orthomyxoviridae |
| 19059 | Upolu virus | Thogotovirus upoluense | Thogotovirus | Orthomyxoviridae |

Comment: I tried that, but then the issue becomes that it only selects the subtype ones and not the ones below that, there are 19000 virus names in there and i first want all of them before i filter. There are many subtypes beyond serotype, Species, No rank, Clade. and this differs for most viruses. Orthomyxo has no clades where as Flaviviruses do